# how to change the height of a label

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a silly error. I currently have the following:

[image]

I would like to have the label (yellow part) be the same height as the textarea. Here is my css:

```
.labelbox{
            border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
            border-top-left-radius: 2em;
            padding: 8px;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            background: #e9f939; /* Old browsers */
            padding-right: 5px;
            color:black;
            float:left;
            width:17.5%;
        } 

.inputbox{
            width: 80%;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
            border-top-right-radius: 2em;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #ececec;
            display: inline;
            padding: 8px;
            font-size: 100%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 1%;
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <label class="labelbox" style="display:inline-block" for="textareacontactus">Type Message</label>
 <textarea maxlength="1000" class="inputbox" rows="6" style="resize: none;height" ng-model="textareacontactus" ng-minlength="20" name="textareacontactus" id="textareacontactus" data-role="none"></textarea required>
```

Now in my HTML I have used `style="height:20%"` but nothing seems to change and I've got no clue why. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you extend your example code a bit such that it helps us reproduce the issue? (It also helps if you *trim* the current code a bit, down to only the relevant bits.)

Comment: you use a css file, and inline styles, remove the inline styles and set them in the css file. you set `display: inline-block` inline and `display: block;`in your css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A make fix solution for you: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9SYa/)

Just add `line-height:6em;` to the `.labelbox`.

Comment: Could perhaps explain the difference between using % and em?

Comment: Even though, `em` and `%` values are relative, there lies an inherent difference between the two. [*Here's an article that will shed more light on it*](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/). For starters, consider using `em` with textual elements and `%` for container elements like `div`. Also, instead of using percentages to make the design respond to layout changes, consider using `min-width`, `max-width`, "min-height` and `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add to the .labelbox


padding-top: 3em;
padding-bottom: 3em;
```